# extract only successful counts from data

Tags: sql

My data includes both success and failure transaction. I need only net counts `i.e. success-failure = net`. (Using sql only)

```
id     product    txn_num   amount
1      sale       6737       40
2      failure    f6737     -40
3      sale       5635       70
4      sale       3467       80
5      failure    3467      -80
6      sale       3468       80
7      failure    3468      -80
```

My data is not structured.
I want to calculate net amount considering variation in `txn_num` using sql.
IF product is failure then it needs to be removed with sale row and amount need not to be included in result.
But Problem is, in data failure transaction number not starting with 'f' symbol.
The only way to resolve this issue is compare both `amount` and `txn_num` column to get net result.

Solve it using sql only.

Result should be

```
count=1, Amount=70, product=sale, id=4
```

Comment: pls show whats your desired result should be

Comment: Uhh...what counts as success or failure based your table??

Comment: You should include a section where you list what you tried already. Just saying "Solve it using sql only" makes it sound like this is some school assignment that you copy & pasted here.

Comment: Result is count=1, Amount=70, product=sale, id=4

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please give more information. What is the DBMS you are using, and what have you tried so far??

Answer (score 0):

When a transaction is cancelled there's a new row with the same `txn_num` but a negative `amount`?
So you simply have to search for a `txn_num` with a single row or a `SUM(amount) <> 0`

```
select 
   min(id), min(product), txn_num, sum(amount)
from tab
group by txn_num
having sum(amount) <> 0  -- or count(*) = 1
```